# How can I bind a click event to the last child if the last child element changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume we're making a to-do list, How can I append a new list item whenever the last list item is clicked.
In the example code below, the fourth list item retains the click event, but I would like it to be on the last list item each time.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul id="foo">
<li><input placeholder="One"></input></li>
<li><input placeholder="Two"></input></li>
<li><input placeholder="Three"></input></li>
<li><input placeholder="Click Me Add More"></input></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('#foo li:last-child').bind( "click", function(){
        var li = $(this).clone();
        $('#foo').append(li);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jquery 1.7+, use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NeQ5q/

```
 $('#foo').on( "click","li:last-child", function(){
        var li = $(this).off('click').clone();
        $('#foo').append(li);
    })​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#foo li:last-child').bind( "click", function(){
        var li = $(this).clone(true);
        $('#foo li:last-child').unbind( "click");
        $('#foo').append(li);
    })​
```

Instead use `.on()`  and `.off()`

```
$('#foo li:last-child').on( "click", function(){
      var li = $(this).clone(true);
      $('#foo li:last-child').off( "click");
      $('#foo').append(li);
 })​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QBYBn/)**

Answer (score 0):

I was trying bind instead of live

```
$('#foo li:last-child').live( "click", function(){
    var li = $(this).clone();
    $('#foo').append(li);
})
```

Comment: For jquery 1.7+, use .on() instead

Answer (score -1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xu4wc/

```
$('#foo').on( "click","input:last-child", function(){
     var li = $(this).parent().clone();
        $('#foo').append(li);
    })
```